# React Native record video and capture Speech to Text

Tags: react-native, speech-to-text, react-native-camera, amazon-transcribe, react-native-voice

I'm using [React Native Camera](https://github.com/react-native-camera/react-native-camera) to record video. I would also like to transcribe the voice at the same time (speech-to-text). I'm looking at [React Native Voice](https://github.com/react-native-voice/voice) but I don't think I can use both libraries at once (sharing the Mic input).

Wondering if anyone has ideas besides uploading the final video file somewhere to get transcribed.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-voice/voice maybe this can help @Ellery

Comment: scratch the above one! i guess we can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-transcribe-streaming

Comment: @RizwanAtta Does the mic input get shared ? This is what i'm really unclear about. Or would I need to modify React Native Camera to integrate AWS lib you referenced?

Comment: @RizwanAtta Turns out the first one works! Finally got it working today

Comment: @Ellery Familia, please can you help me out how to done this?

Comment: @RavinaVaishnav the libraries worked as expected by just following their implementation guide. I ended up not using this because it’s not reliable, the user can always reject permissions to transcribe on iOS. I’m sure there are better approaches and the easiest is transcribing after the video is uploaded, but that will cost money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.
You can record video with React Native Camera, and using speech-to-text in Voice Library.

For voice library you can see [this](https://fostermade.co/blog/making-speech-to-text-work-with-react-native-and-expo) or [this](https://gilshaan.medium.com/speech-to-text-conversion-in-react-native-using-hooks-use-usestate-and-useeffect-c2b9de6b8a8a) guides.

Comment: Apologies, didn't realize the bounty expired and I couldn't then assign it. I am indeed able to record and transcribe at the same time with React-Native-Voice. I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: Hello, can you please share your solution how you were able to listen and record at the same time? thank you. @ElleryFamilia